# How to get difference between two dates including the both dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Generally this is used for getting the number of days between two dates but it does not
include both dates . It just gives the difference. In order to include both dates,I need to add
one day more to the results. but I am not able to add that as my both date colums are of type
date.

```
Select Case When DATEDIFF(d,DateFrom ,DateTo) is null 
Then  DATEDIFF(d,DateFrom ,DateTo)
else
DATEDIFF(d,DateFrom,DateTo) + 1
End

From Table
```

But it is not working

Comment: "it is not working" is not a helpful problem description

Comment: how could you get null using `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: What is the error you're getting, as the logic is sound

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATEADD(day, 1, DateTo)` to add a day to `DateTo`.

To include this in your `else`: `DATEDIFF(d, DateFrom, DATEADD(day, 1, DateTo))`